# Xubuntu 18.10 - right click on touch pad left clicks on release

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I plugged in a microsoft mouse today with a tilting wheel. Wheel tilts didn't register in software (but did in xev) so I gave up, figured I'd work on it tomorrow. I didn't reconfigure anything, save for sensitivity.

Now, right click on my touchpad left clicks on release. xev shows only mouse button 3 press and release. Swapping button functions just swaps the problem to the left button. It's not hardware, it's software. It isn't isolated to one program, and occurs system-wide.

My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad 300 15-ISK. Solutions given in other posts (which of course I can't find anymore) include disabling ps/2 mouse support (which is useless because I need this touchpad to work), and uninstalling inputattach (which also wants to uninstall xubuntu-core and xubuntu-desktop.)

Reboot doesn't solve the problem. I'm not sure where to go from here. Help?